# How to add a total value at the end of a datatable column that has an expression?

Tags: wpf, datatable, datagrid, sum

I want to add a total value at the end of a datatable column. But I can't do it because the column has an expression. The code is as below. Please help!

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("ColB", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("ColSum", typeof(double));

            table.Rows.Add(1.23, 2.34, null);
            table.Rows.Add(2.34, 3.45, null);
            table.Rows.Add(3.45, 4.56, null);

            table.Columns["ColSum"].Expression = "ColA + ColB";
            double total = (double)table.Compute("Sum(ColSum)", "");

            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["ColSum"] = total; 
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
            //Can't add total value at the end of ColSum because this column has an expression. How to solve the problem ?

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't do it because the column has an expression

True. That's a fact so get rid of the expression and calculate the sum yourself:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("ColB", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("ColSum", typeof(double));

table.Rows.Add(1.23, 2.34, 1.23 + 3.45);
table.Rows.Add(2.34, 3.45, 2.34 + 3.45);
table.Rows.Add(3.45, 4.56, 3.45 + 4.56);

double total = (double)table.Compute("Sum(ColSum)", "");

DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
dr["ColSum"] = total;
table.Rows.Add(dr);
```

That's the only viable option if you choose to represent your data using a `DataTable`.

The other option is of course to create your own view model.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe there is no a truly simple method.

Comment: This is as simple as it gets using a `DataTable`. You *cannot* explicitly set the value of an expression column.